# PHP 5.5 setlocale() not working in CLI on Windows?

Tags: php

I'm diagnosing some user problems with German locales. Running

```
php -r "setlocale(LC_ALL, array('de_DE','deu_deu)); echo 10.01;"
```

gives

```
10.01
```

Running

```
<?php
echo(setlocale(LC_ALL,array('de_DE','deu_deu')));
echo 10.01;
```

via WAMP stack gives

```
German_Germany.1252 10,01
```

This shows that locale is active and the decimal_point has changed.

Is it a known restricting that `setlocale` doesn't work in CLI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After opening an issue with PHP it turns indeed out to be a bug: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=65230

Funny (or rather not) is that obviously broken behavior won't get fixed or even documented:

> And after all, locale has such issues on any platform. The solution is to use intl or custom localization functionality.